# Figure out function signatures of precompiled functions during JIT in LLVM

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am currently working on implementing a JIT compiler using LLVM. 
The problem I have is that a portion of the compiler runtime is implemented in C.

From my intermediate representation, I can generate all native functions. However, certain operations in the language require calls to these external C-functions.

The problem I have is that I do not from my IR know the exact types of parameters passed to these functions, they might take an int, or they might take a float. The previous code generation was based on C, and the weak typing of C allowed to call these functions with no hassle. However, when generating LLVM-IR I need to know the signatures of these pre-compiled functions, is there any way to figure out the signature using the orc-API or some other method, or would it be better to just hard code the configuration for each necessary function?

Comment: This is partly related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865191/how-to-call-a-jited-llvm-function-with-unknown-type However, orc is not used and these functions I aim to generate a call instruction for already exists in the runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I implemented for this problem follows the following simple scheme.

During compilation calls to these functions are generated the signature simply being based on what parameters and return values are passed to the pre-compiled function in question.

This works well for my example since I use the C calling convention with LLVM. The C calling convention to quote the LLVM homepage tolerates mismatch:

"This calling convention (the default if no other calling convention is specified) matches the target C calling conventions. This calling convention supports varargs function calls and tolerates some mismatch in the declared prototype and implemented declaration of the function (as does normal C)." [1]: https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#calling-conventions